# Deploying React js Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm super new to the world of React 
I built a single page application.

Can I deploy the app to GoDaddy server? How?

I used create-react-app

Bests

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Answer (score 1):

First of all you go for a firebase web host.

> npm run build

it will generate a build file using `npm run build`. If it is not working just 
   follow the procedures in [create build system](https://medium.com/underdog-io-engineering/create-a-build-system-for-your-react-app-in-5-minutes-or-less-91c501a30b1d)

> npm install firebase --save

create a project in your [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) account.
generated build file to a new folder then run

> firebase init

firebase will get initialize and select created project.
choose "Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
" from your terminal.
run:

> firebase deploy

you will get a deployed project link

Comment: Thank you Pranav, this helps a lot.